# SQL query rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Edit: I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to run my queries.
Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition (64-bit) I guess.

I've got a complex query to run. I had no idea how to do it, so I went and write a query that's around 500 rows and many joins. Not how things should be dome.

My data structure is:

```
id        user_id       question_id     answer1     
1         1             1               a           
2         1             2               c           
3         1             3               a           
4         2             1               c           
5         2             2               a           
...       ...           ...             ...
```

There are over 700 users. Each user has answered around 60 questions (times 2, there are 2 answers to each question, but this is irrelevant if I can get a nice query for the first answer). There are some questions I have no interest in (and should actually skip).

My current result is the following (good result, but the query is way too heave):

```
user_id    q1    q2    q3    q4    q8    q9    ...   q60
1          a     b     c     d     b     a     ...   a
2          b     a     c     a     c     b     ...   w
3          y     a     w     ...   ...
```

So, basically I'd like to create an array, say `[1,2,3,4,8,9]`, saying I am interested in those question id's, and query so I get those columns as the above example. I have no idea how to do this.

My current query is in the likes of:

```
SELECT C.user_id, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q8, ...
FROM (
  SELECT A.user_id, Q1, // and here tons of unions
```

Comment: In that case you have to write Dynamic Sql i.e. using array list generate query and then exec it. In sql server you can run dynamic query by EXEC("Select ...")

Comment: Your sample data and output dont match, is that intentional?
Also, tag your DBMS pls.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Oracle. Yes, output doesn't match, didn't really pay attention to that. The content doesn't matter, it's about the table structure.

Comment: "*I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio*" doesn't fit with "I use Oracle" SMSS can't be used together with Oracle.

Comment: Then I have no idea. I do use MS SQL Server Management Studio. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19057/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server-when-columns-are-string-data seems to discuss the same problem, but no real answer...

Comment: If you are using SMSS, you are also using SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: simplified using only answer1:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(id INT,user_id INT,question_id INT,answer1 VARCHAR(1),answer2 VARCHAR(1));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES     
 (1,1,1,'a','x')           
,(2,1,2,'c','y')           
,(3,1,3,'a','y')           
,(4,2,1,'c','y')         
,(5,2,2,'a','x');

WITH AllAnswers AS
(
    SELECT p.*
    FROM
    (
        SELECT tbl.user_id
              ,'q' + CAST(tbl.question_id AS VARCHAR(10)) AS columnName
              ,answer1
        FROM @tbl AS tbl
    ) AS x
    PIVOT
    (
        MIN(answer1) FOR columnName IN(q1,q2,q3 /*Add your question numbers here*/)
    ) AS p
)
SELECT aa.user_id 
      ,aa.q1
      ,aa.q2
      ,aa.q3 
      /*Get only the questions you want*/
FROM AllAnswers AS aa

/* Result

user_id q1  q2  q3
1       a   c   a
2       c   a   NULL

*/
```

Could this be a solution for you:

Just a short explanation: As you write about two answers for each question I put this second answer into the test set. To allow a PIVOT with more than one column I use the trick to concat both answers as a pseudo-XML. This is pivoted and taken apart by its internal index again.

The result is a list of all users with all there answers to all questions. With the last SELECT you can choose which questions / answers you want to fetch.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(id INT,user_id INT,question_id INT,answer1 VARCHAR(1),answer2 VARCHAR(1));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES     
 (1,1,1,'a','x')           
,(2,1,2,'c','y')           
,(3,1,3,'a','y')           
,(4,2,1,'c','y')         
,(5,2,2,'a','x');

WITH AllAnswers AS
(
    SELECT p.user_id
          ,CAST(p.q1 AS XML).value('x[1]','varchar(1)') AS q1_1
          ,CAST(p.q1 AS XML).value('x[2]','varchar(1)') AS q1_2
          ,CAST(p.q2 AS XML).value('x[1]','varchar(1)') AS q2_1
          ,CAST(p.q2 AS XML).value('x[2]','varchar(1)') AS q2_2
          ,CAST(p.q3 AS XML).value('x[1]','varchar(1)') AS q3_1
          ,CAST(p.q3 AS XML).value('x[2]','varchar(1)') AS q3_2
          /*Add all your question numbers here*/
    FROM
    (
        SELECT tbl.user_id
              ,'q' + CAST(tbl.question_id AS VARCHAR(10)) AS columnName
              ,'<x>' + ISNULL(answer1,'') + '</x><x>' + ISNULL(answer2,'') + '</x>' AS BothAnswers
        FROM @tbl AS tbl
    ) AS x
    PIVOT
    (
        MIN(BothAnswers) FOR columnName IN(q1,q2,q3 /*Add your question numbers here*/)
    ) AS p
)
SELECT aa.user_id 
      ,aa.q1_1 
      ,aa.q1_2 
      ,aa.q2_1 
      ,aa.q2_2 
      ,aa.q3_1 
      ,aa.q3_2 
      /*Get only the questions you want*/
FROM AllAnswers AS aa
```

Comment: I'll get to work on this, thanks for the elaborate example! With the "two answers", I mean that the table has two answer columns (see the 'answer1', there is also an 'answer2'). I do not need to look at the 2nd answer: I want two result tables, one for answer1 and one for answer2. So I could use the query and set it to take the answer from column answer1, and then the same query but from the anwer2 column.

Comment: @Tjab, I simplified my example to use only answer1. I do not think, that this can be done much easier... In the final SELECT you have the free choice to select only the columns you want

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT [user_id], 
         [answer1],
         row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY [user_id] ORDER BY [question_id]) rn
  FROM [table]
) d
PIVOT
(
  MAX([answer1])
  FOR rn in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])
) piv
```

Works very well, for one bug. `user_id = 1` has no answers for `question_id = 3`, but it has for `question_id = 4`. My result places the answer on `4` in to `3`:

```
user_id   1    2    3    4    5    6
1         a    b    c         NULL NULL
2         a    b    c    d    NULL NULL
```

With this data:

```
user_id    question_id    answer1
1          1              a
1          2              b
1          4              c
1          5                                      (anwer1 = empty string)
1          6              NULL
2          1              a
2          2              b
2          4              c
2          5              d
2          6              NULL
```

Should have given:

```
user_id   1    2    3    4    5    6
1         a    b    NULL c         NULL
2         a    b    NULL c    d    NULL
```

So the bug: if no record is found, the answer to the 'next question' is used.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER will come back with a running number. If there is no answer in the table, your "rn" will skip  one value. You could try using a Tally-Table, but my approach in my answer is surely more reliable... what's wrong with it?

Comment: Hi, could you solve your problem? Did my (edited) answer help you? If yes, it would be very kind to vote it up and - if it solved you problem - mark it as accepted, thx!

Comment: Yes, thanks! Sorry I got back so very, very late. Marked as accepted, thanks again!